# Mean of the means / ANOVA with percentages

Tags: logistic, anova, discrete-data

I subjected aliquots of 4 replicates (microorganism cultures) to 3 different treatments + control.
In each treatment, I :

1- counted the number of cells whose colour changed in 100 cells of each replicate; and
2- measured the diameter of 50 cells in each aliquot of each replicate

I presented this data as a percentage in the 1st case and the mean of the means in the 2nd case. I I wanted to do a one-way ANOVA to see if the treatments changed the colour (1st case) and/or the diameter (2nd case), and if so, which treatment had the greatest effect in both cases.
Can I do a logit transformation of the percentages and then an ANOVA of the 1st case data? It is correct to perform an ANOVA with the average of the replicates for each treatment or with all measurements together?

Comment: Welcome to cv, Kikau. You have 4 replucates in each treatment, right? Then your suggestions sound reasonable; you would have four logit values in each group. I don't seem to understand what you mean by "all measurements together", though. For 1), you could also use a chisquare test.